# If every bounded subsequence of a sequence converges to some L, then the sequence converges to some L.

Tags: real-analysis

I know that this statement is true for every convergent subsequence. However, as the requirement of these subsequences is to be bounded, would this change the truth of the statement?

Answer (score 3):

This is false. Take for instance the sequence $$0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, ....$$ Every subsequence of this sequence that is bounded converges to $0$, but the sequence does not converge.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification.